# Configuration file for Silverlight client, which is working with WCF Polling Duplex Service

Tags: c#, wcf, configuration, silverlight-4.0

can I use ServiceReference.config file for configuring PullingDuplexHttpBinding? If yes, please tell me how. I don't have any problems with configuring client programmatic, but I need to use config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we using Silverlight 4 and WCF with PullingDuplexHttpBinding, we can't configure client with using ServiceReference.config, we need to do it in code.
But we can do it with custom binding.

Really good explanation you can see [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/b389aa23-9466-4f83-94ba-1a6adb79bf02).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by registering a custom binding extension.  There is a complete example on [Peter McGratten's blog](http://petermcg.wordpress.com/2008/10/23/configuring-silverlight-2-polling-duplex-config/).

Comment: Thank you for help. But this article about Silverlight 2 and doesn't say anything about using config file on client.

Comment: @Michael M.: But configuration is the same for the client as it is on the server...

Comment: You absolutely right, if we talk about "built-in" bindings. For example BasicHttpBinding. But I'm using PullingDuplexHttpBinding which available with Silverlight SDK. If you add service reference on WCF Pulling Duplex service VS 2010 will generate services references and ServiceReference.config

Comment: But ServiceReference.config will contain only one row "<configuration />". And I need to create client like this: "var duplexServiceClient = new DuplexnServiceClient(new PollingDuplexHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/DuplexService.svc"));".  I know that I can use resource file for storing information about endpoint, but I hope we have better way for storing endpoint information. Sorry, may be my explanation  isn't very clear...